# How make template member function specialization from inherited class?

Tags: c++

Need some help about template member function specialization as following code;

```
class Base
{
    public:
        template <int>  void MyFunc();
};


class Object : public Base
{
    public:
        //template <int>    void MyFunc(); // with this works !!!

        template <> void MyFunc<3>()
        {
        }
};
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with this code?  Are you expecting these functions to behave as if they are `virtual`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can't.

The reason is that when the compiler sees the declaration of Object, it doesn't know anything about Base's template functions. So it can't generate a specialization of MyFunc for Object.

The only way to make this work is to declare the specialization of MyFunc in the Base class.

Member function templates are not inherited.